# Error php, xampp, se rompieron todos mis programas

Tags: php, xampp

desde ayer todos mis programas crashearon, uno en particular con el que eh estado trabajando me dejo de mostrar apartados del html, y también me dejaron de funcionar métodos de java script, el código en la mas mínimo lo eh movido. tenia php 8.1.2 y baje a 8.0.15 pensé que ese era el error pero no, igualmente hice lo mismo con xampp. A alguien le a pasado algo similar? alguna actualización de Windows? algún otro error? estoy pensando en instalar Windows desde cero jaja

Comment: Sin ver qué errores te salen ahora, cómo cambiaste php, cómo cambiaste wamp, etc, imposible opinar cualquier cosa. Ponte en el lugar de quien lea ésto

Comment: pues es que nunca me dio ningún error, el xampp conectaba sin problema, alguna vez recuerdo bajamente un mensaje en visual studió acerca de mi php, pero si te soy sincero no recuerdo que decía  y todavía en este momento no me muestra ningún error jajaj. Como sea, a partir de que se crashearon todos mis programas, en cuestión de xampp desinstale el programa, borre sus carpetas y baje a una versión anterior. En cuestión de php descargue la 8.0.15 desde su pagina, la coloque en disco local y desde variables de entorno modifique el Path. para no fonciono. _--_

Comment: Pues hay (y había) que comenzar por revisar los logs de PHP y ver cómo está fallando. Lo que no funciona de Javascript, ver la consola del navegador y ver qué error muestra. Tu pregunta sigue siendo "algo falló", sigue fuera de alcance. Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir estos detalles que te comento. O puedes seguir yendo por la opción nuclear, reiniciar windows, comenzar tus proyectos de cero y tal ;)